# Postgresql, update or insert based by case

Tags: postgresql, case-when

The update and insert statements work when i run them alone and without a transaction...

But i like to execute both in the given order in the transaction and also get the RETURNING value every time - no matter if it inserts or updates - how do i do this`?

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE globaldata SET valuetext=(SELECT (CAST(coalesce(valuetext, '0') AS integer) + 1) FROM globaldata WHERE keyname='bb') WHERE keyname='bb' RETURNING valuetext;
INSERT INTO globaldata (keyname, valuetext)SELECT 'bb', '1' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM globaldata WHERE keyname='bb') RETURNING valuetext;
COMMIT;
```

I tried to wrap the update and insert statements by CASE WHEN THEN...but i didnt succeed...

I like to do something like:

```
BEGIN;
CASE
    WHEN (select count(id) from globaldata where keyname='bb') > 0 THEN
UPDATE globaldata SET valuetext=(SELECT (CAST(coalesce(valuetext, '0') AS integer) + 1) FROM globaldata WHERE keyname='bb') WHERE keyname='bb' RETURNING valuetext;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO globaldata (keyname, valuetext)SELECT 'bb', '1' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM globaldata WHERE keyname='bb') RETURNING valuetext;
END;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: [INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING/UPDATE ("UPSERT")](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#INSERT_..._ON_CONFLICT_DO_NOTHING.2FUPDATE_.28.22UPSERT.22.29)

Comment: what should the conflict be based on in this example? Its either insert if it doesn't exists - otherwise update ...

Comment: It will work if the unique constraint on `globaldata.keyname` is exists: `insert into globaldata(keyname, valuetext) values ('bb', '1') on conflict (keyname) do update set valuetext = (coalesce(valuetext,'0'))::int + 1 returning *;` Simpler a bit, but, as I say, the `keyname` field should be marked as unique.

Comment: OMG! This is like 1000 times easier! And it actually return the entire row! thanks´you so much! Please leave an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

I have been wanting to do this as well, after looking into it and a little trial and error I came up with this working solution.

use the `with` statement

```
with
u as (
  update my_table
    set some_value = $2
  where
    id = $1
  returning *
)
,
i as (
  insert into my_table (id, some_value)
    select $1, $2
  where 
    not exists(select * from u)
  returning *
)

select * from u
union
select * from i;
```

Try the update first returning the row updated, if there is no row returned from the update, then insert the row returning the inserted row.  Then select a union of the returned values form the update and the insert, since only one will happen you will only get one row returned.

Hope this helps

Comment: That is a smart way to check if update is required or insert is required. If this  is confusing to some, they can go for the CASE statement and decide to update or insert based on the result of the CASE statement.

Answer (score 0):

try using `DO`

**Updated**

```
       do 
        $$
        declare _valuetext text;
        BEGIN
        if
            (select count(id) from globaldata where keyname='bb') > 0 THEN
        UPDATE globaldata SET valuetext=(SELECT (CAST(coalesce(valuetext, '0') AS integer) + 1) FROM globaldata WHERE keyname='bb') WHERE keyname='bb' RETURNING valuetext into _valuetext
    ;
raise info '%','_valuetext is '||_valuetext;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO globaldata (keyname, valuetext)SELECT 'bb', '1' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM globaldata WHERE keyname='bb') 
    RETURNING valuetext  into _valuetext
    ;
raise info '%','_valuetext is '||_valuetext;
         end if;
            END;
            $$
            ;
```

Comment: ERROR:  query has no destination for result data. But if you know how to do it you can just write some other statements inside the validation?

Comment: Btw... is all the code run like a transaction by the do syntax? or? because when i put it inside a begin/commit - it doesn't work... what syntax is this? what is the name?

Comment: if you open transaction - it runs in it. eg `begin; do $$ begin _something end;$$ commit;` should be in rollbackable

Comment: Sorry - i forgot a semicolon... One last thing... the result - the interger value is not actually returned (to the code) like the RETURNING does it normally... I need to return the value of the variable "_valuetext" - how do i do this?

Comment: if the result is not returned from the sql - we have solved nothing... that was the main issue...

Comment: return where? it should be raised as info

Comment: before the code is use full the data need to be returned ... like normal sql: select field from table...

Comment: if you want the set to be returned, use function instead. anonymous plsql block can perform action, returning nothng. just add what you want to return and you have function. btw anyway, why don't you use 9.5 "UPSERT"?..