# INSERT in CASE expression from subselect PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, case

I am trying to create a query like this

```
WITH insert1 as (),
...
subselect1 as (SELECT
   (CASE
     WHEN %s is NOT NULL THEN
          (INSERT INTO Duration (duration)
          VALUES (ROW (%s, %s)) RETURNING id as id_duration)
     ELSE
          (INSERT INTO Distance (length)
          VALUES (ROW (%s, %s)) RETURNING id as id_distance)
       END)),
...
INSERT INTO FinalTable...
```

I'm having trouble with the syntax, I know. Do you accomplish this by with Insert into?

**My plan is:**
By one **WITH** statement make several insertions with returning values and finally insert to the FinalTable. Having only INSERT and RETURNING values it works great - I have to refer them in FinalTable e.g. (`SELECT id_point from insert3`).

But this case - I would like to return value from insert, wrapped in **CASE** (%s means parametrized query, variables passed from python). So in case first %s is **NOT NULL**, I have to insert to table Duration, else I have to insert to table Distance.

When inserting in FinalTable, I have references to these tables (columns idDistance, idDuration) - so I would like to write smth like (..., (`SELECT id_duration from subselect1`), (`SELECT id_distance from subselect1`)...)

What's wrong with my syntax?

Comment: You can't use `INSERT` inside a CASE expression.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, will you please comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38424963/postgresql-update-or-insert-based-by-case

Comment: `PL/pgSQL` CASE and `SQL` CASE are not the same thing.

Comment: The solution in that question is using a PL/pgSQL `CASE` [**statement**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#id-1.8.8.8.6.7) whereas you are using a SQL `CASE` [**expression**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)

Comment: Inserting into a single column using a `row()` construction seems extremely strange to me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I use `row()` for inserting values to column with composite type (duration/length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very unclear to me what you are trying to achieve, but maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
WITH insert1 as (
...
),
insert_duration (id_duration) as (
  insert into duration (duration, ....) 
  select .... 
  from (
      values (..),(..)
  ) as t(...)
  where $1 IS NOT NULL --<< first branch of your CASE expression
  returning id
), 
insert_distance (id_distance) as (
  insert into distance (length, ...) 
  select .... 
  from (
      values (..),(..)
  ) as t(...)
  where $1 IS NULL --<< ELSE branch of your CASE expression
  returning id
)
INSERT INTO final_table 
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Seems your idea is not for my case - I would like to divide insertions the tables (duration, distance) based on the passed variable value from the Python script (if NULL, no need to insert otherwise insert). So I have nowhere select from (in branches), because it is simply the values

Comment: @Jane: that would still work, see my edit. You can "select" from the values you want to insert

Comment: In case I have to insert an array of values (I need to check if array is exist) - select.. from values (unnest(array)) it throws an error `set-returning functions are not allowed in VALUES`... What you would advise?)